# map function save result to an object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

this is what my response looks like

```
data: [
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "Oliver Green",
        email: "test@gmail.com",
        contacts: "09179878564"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Orval McLaughlin",
        email: "okoch@example.org",
        contacts: "09083692343",
    }
]
```

I used the map function to get the user id and user name, now what I'm trying to do is to save all of the result to an Object

```
data(){
    return {
        autoComplete:{},
    }
},

let vm = this;
response.data.data.map((user) =>
{
    return vm.autoComplete = { [user.id] : user.name};
});
```

I get the result however I'm only getting one result

```
autoComplete:Object
    2:"Orval McLaughlin"
```

the result should be

```
autoComplete:Object
    3: "Oliver Green"
    2: "Orval McLaughlin"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the object from `map()` not the result of an assignment. You are currently assigning `vm.autoComplete` on each iteration.  After you do this you can assign the output of `map` to the variable you want:

```js
let data = [
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "Oliver Green",
        email: "test@gmail.com",
        contacts: "09179878564"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Orval McLaughlin",
        email: "okoch@example.org",
        contacts: "09083692343",
    }
]
let autoComplete = data.map((user) => {
    return { [user.id] : user.name};
});

console.log(autoComplete)
```

EDIT:

If you want an object instead of an array, you should use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) because `map()` always returns an array:

```js
let data = [
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "Oliver Green",
        email: "test@gmail.com",
        contacts: "09179878564"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Orval McLaughlin",
        email: "okoch@example.org",
        contacts: "09083692343",
    }
]
let autoComplete = data.reduce((obj, user) =>{
    obj[user.id] = user.name; // this assumes user.id will be unique
    return obj
}, {});

console.log(autoComplete)
```

Comment: okay i got already the result however is it possible to become object only ? not wrap by an array

Comment: my result now looks like this autoComplete:Array[2]
0:Object
1:Object 
this should be autoComplete:Object
    3: "Oliver Green"
    2: "Orval McLaughlin"

Comment: @Beginner you should use `reduce` in that case. See the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for not wrapping it in array.

```
response.data.data.map((user) => {
return vm.autoComplete = Object.assign(vm.autoComplete, {[user.id] : user.name}); }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the autoComplete be overwrite for each.

Maybe you can try these:

```
  data(){
      return {
          autoComplete:{},
      }
  },

  let vm = this;

  vm.autoComplete = response.data.data.map((user) => {
      return { [user.id] : user.name};
  });
```